# GA4 - Trigger events via PHP

Tags: php, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

I use a Google Tag Manager (GTM) account to send events to Google Analytics 4 (GA4). I have a tag configured in my GTM that triggers when the page URL contains a specific parameter. This tag gets the parameter in the URL and sends a custom event called 'custom_purchase_event' to GA4. GA4 receives it, and the value is visible on the Engagement -> Events page.

A few days ago, we noticed that for some particular users, the tag was not being triggered, and therefore the event didn't reach GA4. I thought that a better solution would be to trigger the events via PHP. I tried to use the [Measurement Protocol for GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag) but I can't get it to work. I get a 204 status, but the event doesn't show on GA4.
I'm using Guzzle to make the request:

```
// Create a Guzzle HTTP client
$client = new Client();

$payload = [
     'client_id' => '12345_XXX',
     'events' => [
          [
               'name' => 'custom_purchase_event',
               'params' => [
                    'value' => $value,
                    'discount' => $discount,
                    'currency' => $currency,
                    'items' => [
                         "item": "1",
                         "item_id": "1_123456XXX",
                         "item_name": "Chair",
                    ]
               ]
          ]
      ]
];

// Send POST request to GA4 Measurement Protocol API using Guzzle
$response = $client->post("https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect", [
     'query' => [
          'api_secret' => $this->api_secret,
          'measurement_id' => $this->measurement_id
     ],
     'json' => json_encode($payload),
     'headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     ]
]);
```

Is there a way of triggering events in GA4 via PHP?

Comment: The point of having an explicit `json` option, is that Guzzle itself will encode the data you pass via it, as JSON. So you are currently encoding what you are sending as JSON _twice_, and I doubt the receiving end will properly process that.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, @CBroe! I've removed the `json_encode`, but I still don't see the event being triggered in GA4.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/validating-events: _"The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol for Google Analytics 4 does not return HTTP error codes, even if an event is malformed or missing required parameters. To ensure your events are valid, you should test them against the Measurement Protocol Validation Server before deploying them to production."_ - so I'd try that first of all now.